# Calling a JQuery function onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery function which displays a hidden div tag. So right now it  works as soon as the document loads but I want to take affect only when a button is click. I tried to create a function and named it hello with the same JQuery code in it but it didn't work.

JQuery Function

```
$("#Signers").show(30,function() {
 });
```

Button

```
<a href="#x" onclick ="validateEmailAddress();hello()"><span>Confirm</span></a>
```

Please guide me on this.

Thanks...

Comment: So you did `function hello() { $("#Signers").show() }` ? What is the error in the developer console?

Comment: Where's your button? Where's your function?

Comment: @j08691 this is the button `<a href="#x" onclick ="validateEmailAddress();hello()"><span>Confirm</span></a>`

Comment: If the function `hello` exists (see comment above), does the function `validateEmailAddress` exist and return without error?

Comment: @Daniel Looks like a link to me

Comment: Button is Confirm.

Comment: $.show is not a function, it's a jQuery method

Comment: @j08691 Yes but he's using it as a button, since he has the `onclick` event binded to it, and he decided it to be an `a` element for some reason that seems to not be relevant to the question itself!

Comment: @yezzzz I know it's a JQuery method. What are you telling me out of this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap your jQuery function inside of a JavaScript function, and make sure that you actually have an element with the ID `Signers`, and your code will work.

Also, do not forget to include jQuery.

Working example:

```js
function validateEmailAddress() {
  console.log('Email');
}

function hello() {
  console.log('JavaScript');
  
  $("#Signers").show(30, function() {
    // do something after show
    console.log('jQuery');
  });
}
```

```css
/** 
 * This CSS is just here to hide and stylize #Singers, it's 
 * not actually needed for the slution 
 **/
 
#Signers {
    display: none;
    font-size: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#x" onclick="validateEmailAddress();hello()"><span>Confirm</span></a>
<div id="Signers">#Singers</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for me when I put the JQuery code inside a function. The div doesn't show up.

Comment: The above is proven to work. Simply divide and conquer, slowly adding parts of your code into the above example until you find the part of your code that is causing it to break. The most likely culprits are a duplicate function name, or CSS overrides (such as `display: none !important`). If your jQuery works and you're also getting the `console.log('JavaScript')`, then it's probably actually firing, just not showing up due to higher specificity on the hiding.

Comment: @Mike Did you put the function inside `$(document).ready()`? That won't work, because `onclick` can only call functions in the global scope.\

Comment: @Barmar. This is how I am doing it. `function hello() {
  $("#Signers").show(5,function() {}); 
 }`

Comment: @Mike Then it should work just like in the answer. Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Believe or not. I don't see any errors on the developer console. As I said this works if I put the code outside the function but the JQuery code inside the function doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe I am not calling it when document loads therefore it doesn't work onClick. It works this way fine `$("#Signers").show(2,function() {});`

Answer (score 1):

You mean when document will load your div tag (with id "Singers") will be hidden. And when a button will be clicked then the div will appear. Isn't it?

If it is then the correct way to do that is below:

1.add style

```
<style>
#Signers{display:none;}
</style>
```

2.add js

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //jquery code
    });
    function hello(){
        $("#Signers").show(30,function() {}); 
    }

</script>
```

Comment: This is what I have been doing but it is not. Without putting the JQuery code inside the function it works but it stops working if I put the code inside a function and call it.

Comment: May be i can guess what you are doing.. You should place the hello function defination outside $(document).ready(function(){}); You can see my edited ans

Comment: It prints the hello alert. Which is very strange.

Comment: Can you show me your code. Without seeing its hard to take decision.

Comment: There you go. `function hello() {
     $("#Signers").show(100,function() {}); 
     alert('hello');
 }`

Comment: It prints hello though but it doesn't show the div Signers

Comment: avoid alert('hello') function. just do what i have done above. Check spelling of the id "Singers".

Comment: I did that for testing purposes.

Comment: is there any div whose id is "Singers" in your html code ?

Comment: It's there Sadhon that is why I have been telling you that alert works.

Answer (score -1):

I finally resolved it. I know in above answers the function is working as expected but in my case none of them worked by putting the JQuery code inside a JS function. What I did that I declared the ready function which basically invoked the JS function and onClick event the function works as desired.

```
function hello(){
 $("#Signers").show(30,function() {
 }); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    hello();
  });
```